# Unable to switch users without logging out in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: session, logout

I have two user accounts, one for me and one for my daughter. We used to go to the button in the upper right corner of the desktop screen and click on another user. Usually it works. Now if I do that, a black screen appears and everything seems to be blocked.

Comment: I don't understand. Do both accounts still exist? Have you tried restarting the system? It happens in both accounts?

Comment: Both account exists and work OK, just can't switch between them

Comment: Did anything change recently? Upgrade, install new software, drivers, etc? What graphics card do you have? Any drivers installed for it? Can you switch to the guest session from that menu? Does it work if you log out first? How much RAM do you have? (Sorry for so many questions).

Comment: It's a fresh install of 14.04

Comment: how do you add another user, is another user password protected ?

Comment: To add it: System Settings, then User Accounts. Main user account is password protected, the second one, no.